# How to know when an email has not been sent from a Journey in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a journey in Marketing Cloud which basically sends an email (with an Email activity) and afterwards updates some fields of the campaign member in Sales Cloud (with a Campaign Member activity).
I need to prevent the campaign member from being updated in Sales Cloud if the email has not been actually sent for whatever reason (because it is in a suppression list, it is bounced, it is globally unsubscribed...)

How can I check that to make some decisions within the journey based on that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a query on _Sent Data View ([link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5)) + Journey Activity Data view ([link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_journey_activity.htm&type=5)), all joined with your journey's data entry on Subscriber Key.

You can then use the target data extension in a decision split: 
 - Subscriber Key IS NOT NULL -> means the contact did receive the email. 
 - Otherwise, he did not receive the email.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rachid. Then I have another question. To check this target data extension in a decision split, I need to link it to the Contact Builder, right? If that's the case, how should I link it? I mean, if the Subscriber Key can be NULL, which field should I use to link it with the Contact Key so I can find it from the journey?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, you should link it in Contact Builder with the Suscriber Key. You will use the fact that a Subscriber Key is not in the Data Extension as sign that the contact did not receive the email.